# How to create a single JUnit Report from ./gradlew test

Tags: java, android, junit, junit4, android-testing

I'm adding tests to my Android project and realize that I now need a single JUnit Test report for my Changes Integration Server. Basically the output of `./gradlew test` is

```
<project-root>/app/build/test-results/debug/TEST-StuffTest.xml
      "                       "            /TEST-SomeOtherTest.xml
      "                       "            /TEST-MeThreeTest.xml
```

What I'd like is a single xml file that includes the test results of all these files. Is there a way to do this?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Sorry for not reading the question more carefully.

There should be an automatically-generated XML report in app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.